# If I add Middleware in Startup File. That time not get request in Model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, middleware

This **Middleware** added in the startup file.

```
app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
```

Middleware is

```or-tag-here
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //First, get the incoming request
        var request = await FormatRequest(context.Request);

        //Copy a pointer to the original response body stream
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        //Create a new memory stream...
        using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //...and use that for the temporary response body
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;

            //Continue down the Middleware pipeline, eventually returning to this class
            await _next(context);

            //Format the response from the server
            var response = await FormatResponse(context.Response);

            //TODO: Save log to chosen datastore

            //Copy the contents of the new memory stream (which contains the response) to the original stream, which is then returned to the client.
            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var body = request.Body;

        //This line allows us to set the reader for the request back at the beginning of its stream.
        request.EnableRewind();

        //We now need to read the request stream.  First, we create a new byte[] with the same length as the request stream...
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

        //...Then we copy the entire request stream into the new buffer.
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        //We convert the byte[] into a string using UTF8 encoding...
        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        //..and finally, assign the read body back to the request body, which is allowed because of EnableRewind()
        request.Body = body;

        return $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {bodyAsText}";
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
    {
        //We need to read the response stream from the beginning...
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //...and copy it into a string
        string text = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        //We need to reset the reader for the response so that the client can read it.
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Return the string for the response, including the status code (e.g. 200, 404, 401, etc.)
        return $"{response.StatusCode}: {text}";
    }
}
```

Using this middle for get **request** but then after not that request is passed in the original model class.

This Middleware added in the startup file. That time faced this problem.

So that, Any another way to get request before passed in the model class. I need to get invalid request also.. because I need to insert that in database same as log.

Comment: Can you share your full Configure method of startup.cs?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho only write this ```app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If your Configure method has only this line. What kind of response you want? Why are you calling _next() if you don't have anythigs next in your pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your `FormatRequest`, try to apply below changes:

1.Swap the order of `var body = request.Body;` and `request.EnableRewind();`

2.Before `request.Body = body;` insert `body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Final code:

```
private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        //This line allows us to set the reader for the request back at the beginning of its stream.
        request.EnableRewind();

        var body = request.Body;

        //We now need to read the request stream.  First, we create a new byte[] with the same length as the request stream...
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

        //...Then we copy the entire request stream into the new buffer.
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        //We convert the byte[] into a string using UTF8 encoding...
        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        //..and finally, assign the read body back to the request body, which is allowed because of EnableRewind()
        request.Body = body;

        return $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {bodyAsText}";
    }
```